# Google Places Autocomplete works not consistently

Tags: java, android, google-maps, autocomplete, maps

I'm aware of people whom their autocomplete doesn't work completely. But in my case, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. If I type a random latter, for example, t, it will show autocomplete and will work just fine. And after I tape a few matters more It will say "Can't load search results".
The point is that it is not consistently and I have no idea why.

I don't have billing I have the API free because of the organization option from my school.

Comment: For the consistent result you need to enable billing for your developer account.

Comment: @MaradiyaKrupa I don't have billing I have the API free because of the organization option from my school.

Comment: You can ask them to enable. you won't be charged up to 150,000 request per day. you can check more info  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49023408/google-places-api-free-requests-per-day-after-enabling-billing)

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind is you are missing **Billing Account**.

1. Login Google Cloud Platform
2. Head to Billing menu
3. If you have a previous billing account, you can assign it to your Google Cloud
   project. If not, create a new billing account using your credit/debit card.
4. Try billing account API KEY, it will work fine

Comment: @MaradiyaKrupa I don't have billing I have the API free because of the organization option from my school.